# Error signing file pkcs#7 and bouncycastle java

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pkcs#7, pkcs#11

I'm getting the following error when trying to sign a file.

Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.operator.OperatorCreationException: exception on setup: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: 1.3.14.3.2.26 for provider SunPKCS11-eToken
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder$1.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInfoGenerator.(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInfoGenerator.(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder.createGenerator(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at testapp.Testapp.setUpProvider(Testapp.java:111)
    at testapp.Testapp.main(Testapp.java:74)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: 1.3.14.3.2.26 for provider SunPKCS11-eToken
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:83)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:202)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:688)
    at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:233)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.ProviderJcaJceHelper.createDigest(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.createDigest(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
Java Result: 1

Here is the code:

```
    InputStream cnfStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11config.getBytes());
    Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(cnfStream);
    Security.addProvider(p);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", p);
    ks.load(null, PASSWORD);
    byte[] signedData = sign(data, ks, p);

public static byte[] sign(byte[] data, KeyStore ks, Provider p) throws Exception {

    String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();

    List certList = new ArrayList();
    CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data); //Data to sign

    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
    certList.add(cert); //Adding the X509 Certificate

    Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);

    CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
    //Initializing the the BC's Signer
    ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider(p).build((PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, PASSWORD));

    gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(
            new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
            new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider(p).build())
            .build(sha1Signer, cert));
    //adding the certificate
    gen.addCertificates(certs);
    //Getting the signed data
    CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, false);
    return sigData.getEncoded();
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up solving this on my own.Here is the working code:

```
    private void findProvider() {
        String driver;
        byte[] pkcs11config;
        for (int i = indiceDrivers; i < largoDrivers; i++) {
            driver = DRIVERS[i];
            File f = new File(REPO + driver);
            if (!f.exists()) {
                continue;
            }
            pkcs11config = String
                    .format("name = eToken\n library = %s%s", REPO, driver)
                    .getBytes();
            try {
                InputStream cnfStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11config);
                provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(cnfStream);
                keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", this.provider);
                Security.addProvider(provider);
                keyStore.load(null, password);
                System.out.println("OK: " + driver);
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //Solo con fines de prueba
                System.out.println("ERROR: " + driver);
            }
        }
        if (provider == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Los drivers del token no estan instalados.");
        } else if (provider != null && keyStore == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("El token no esta conectado.");
        }
    }

 public void sign(File input, File output) throws Exception {
        String alias = keyStore.aliases().nextElement();
        List certList = new ArrayList();
        CMSTypedData msg = new CMSProcessableFile(input);
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);
        certList.add(cert);
        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider(provider).build((PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, password));
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(
                new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build())
                .build(sha1Signer, cert));
        gen.addCertificates(certs);
        CMSSignedData sigData = gen.generate(msg, true);

        FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
        fileOuputStream.write(sigData.getEncoded());
        fileOuputStream.flush();
        fileOuputStream.close();
    }
```